# Cannot update TabPage text

Tags: c#, tabs

For some reason the following code does not update the text displayed on the tab during runtime:

```
tabControl.TabPages[i].Text = newProps.plot_title;
//I tried these too but still no cigar
//tabControl.TabPages[i].Refresh();
//tabControl.Refresh();
```

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: This is a single-threaded WinForms application.  So the update is done on the GUI thread.  The contents of the tab are updated without any problem.  Only the tab text cannot be updated. Full code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Show a dialog box to display and allow user to modify the plot's properties
    /// </summary>
    public void EditPlotProperties()
    {
       Graph_Properties currProps = plotControls[tabControl.SelectedIndex].cube.graphProps;
       PlotProperties propsWindow = new PlotProperties(currProps);

       if (propsWindow.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Cancel)
          return;

       Graph_Properties newProps;
       propsWindow.GetGraphProperties(out newProps);

       if (newProps.IsEqual(currProps))
          return;

       LogFile.Instance.Write(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(), 
          "New plot properties:" + newProps.ToString());

       for (int i = 0; i < numPlots; i++)
       {
          if (i == tabControl.SelectedIndex || newProps.apply_all_plots)
          {
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.plot_title = newProps.plot_title;

             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.x_label = newProps.x_label;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.lower_x = newProps.lower_x;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.upper_x = newProps.upper_x;

             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.y_label = newProps.y_label;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.lower_y = newProps.lower_y;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.upper_y = newProps.upper_y;

             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.z_label = newProps.z_label;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.lower_z = newProps.lower_z;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.upper_z = newProps.upper_z;

             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.plot_size = newProps.plot_size;
             plotControls[i].cube.graphProps.channels = newProps.channels;

             plotControls[i].render();

             // TODO: for some reason this doesn't appear to update the tab text
             tabControl.TabPages[i].Text = newProps.plot_title;
             tabControl.Refresh();

             unsavedChanges[i] = true;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I assume this is WinForms? If so, that code works in a simple test project, when called from a button click event.  Are you sure of the values of 'i' and 'plot_title'? Is that line of code being called on the UI thread?

Comment: @Doug Yes it's WinForms, and the application is single-threaded so everything is done in the GUI thread.  The contents of the tab are updated without any problem (by plotControls[i].render() which uses values in newProps).  So all the values are good and it's not an issue with tab refresh either.  It's very puzzling as to why tab contents but not tab text get updated.

Comment: where numPlots comes from? It seems numPlots is not updated.

Comment: @ulreader numPlots was set earlier and keeps track of the number of tabs on the window.  It doesn't change very often and definitely not in this case.   I don't see how that has any bearing.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should wrap your propsWindow dialog in a using statement so it will be disposed.  Have you stepped through in the debugger or added a try-catch to make sure nothing is throwing an exception before it gets to the line setting the tab title?

Comment: @Doug I'm sure there is no exception being thrown anywhere. I have a try/catch at the highest level so nothing will escape (it's singled threaded single language so truly nothing escapes).  Plus plotControls[i].render() worked exactly as expected and unsavedChanges[i] was set exactly as expected.